# System of 3 equations and 1 inequality in 2 variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-optimization

As part of optimization problem I am trying to solve the following system of equations in $x, y \in \mathbb R$

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}
 22x+1+y= \frac a2 x \\
2y+1+x= \frac a8 y\\
x^2+y^2-9<0\\
\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

where $a \in \mathbb R$.

I think there must be some trick how to solve this, but I couldn't find any, so it would be very helpful if someone gives me a hint.

Comment: You can play around with this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0fjbcvjuq8

Comment: Why not solve the first two linear equations first?

Comment: Thank you @MattiP. Well, I tried that, but then I always got stuck - the calculations were then quite complicated, which I do not suppose was the intention.

Comment: I take $a$ to be a fixed parameter. Why do you expect to find a solution, having 3 equations in two unknowns $x$ and $y$  (and an extra inequality)? Your only chance would by that the 3 equations are dependent on each other but this is not the case.

Comment: I have solved the first two equations in terms of parameter a, problem is that it just always gets so complicated, when I want to finally find x and y, that I never succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Plugging $$y=-1-2x+\frac{a}{2}x$$ in the second equation we get
$$\frac{1}{16} \left(a^2 (-x)+20 a x+2 a-48 x-16\right)=0$$
Can you doing further?

Comment: Oh yes, finally, I got the correct answers - checked by Wolfram - but it wasn't nice. I hoped for some better trick, but apparently there is none. Thank you all for helping!